# SQL SERVER - Find out which field is different

Tags: sql-server, field, except

I have 2 records from table fruits below. I am using EXCEPT statement to do a compare - note that the ID field is ignored:

```
ID  Fruit    AmountToday
1    Apple     10
2    Apple     20
```

My SQL is as below:

```
SELECT FRUIT,AMOUNTTODAY FROM FRUITS WHERE ID='1'
EXCEPT
SELECT FRUIT,AMOUNTTODAY FROM FRUITS WHERE ID='2'
```

This currently returns the whole record - but I want to print the field name that is different - i.e AMOUNTTODAY.

Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Comment: you would join your records together using JOIN or CROSS JOIN - then use CASE statements to tell you if the fields were different or not.  Will you always have 2 records?  What if you had more records?

Comment: So if the `2` row was `Pear, 20` instead, would the "different field" be `FRUIT`, `AMOUNTTODAY`, neither or both?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Case statement to interrogate the fields you are interested in:
This uses the first record in your table to compare against the rest of the records.  It counts the differences for [Fruit] and [AmountToday].

```
With t As
(
SELECT  
  Case When Fruit <> (Select Top 1 Fruit From Fruits) Then 1 Else 0 End As FruitDiff,
  Case When AmountToday <> (Select Top 1 AmountToday From Fruits) Then 1 Else 0 End As AmtDiff
FROM FRUITS 
)
Select 
Sum(FruitDiff) As FruitDiffs,
Sum(AmtDiff) As AmtDiffs
From t
```

Result:

```
FruitDiffs  AmtDiffs

0             1
```